# Page.Init and Page.PostBack

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I know this is a very basic question, but I cannot find the answer.  There are lots of web pages that say page.init does not fire on a post back e.g. here: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/interview/exclusive/x3224-what-is-the-difference-between-the-pageinit-and-pageload-events.aspx.  Please see the code below:

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        MsgBox("Test Init") 'Line 5
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Page.IsPostBack = True Then
            MsgBox("PostBack") 'line 9
        End If
        MsgBox("Test Load")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Text = "Hello"
    End Sub
End Class
```

The message box on line 5 and line 9 fire every time I click the button.  This means that the Init event is fired on a postback.  I have obviously forgotten something very basic.

Comment: The MsgBox is not work on asp.net. If you try to see whats runs there use the `Debug.Write()`, or just write to any control.

Answer (score 1):

From your reference page:

<strike>When you postback to any page, the Page_Init event doesn't fire.</strike>

This is totally wrong.

Page_Init is always fired - actually the page cycle is not change at all.

Comment: Is there ever a scenario when it does not fire?

Comment: Please see Gregor Primar's answer.  I think he disagrees.

Comment: @w0051977 not much to say, you say it also, the init is always runs.